# How to visualize waveforms generated by BOSS SY-300 guitar synth on Windows 10?

Tags: guitar-effects, synthesizer, synthesis, sound-design

I'm crafting new tones on the BOSS SY-300 guitar synth and visualizing the waveforms would help a lot.

If I run an EHX Superego into the SY-300 for infinite sustain, is there a way that I can run an oscilloscope on my Windows 10 machine so that I can see the waveforms in real time?

Comment: There is an online oscilloscope at
https://academo.org/demos/virtual-oscilloscope/ To be honest, I haven't tried it out, so I'm not sure if it updates in real time, but unless you're willing to put out for a commercial oscilloscope, you don't have many options.

Comment: Could I just ask… why do you think looking at an oscilloscope will help you voice synths? I've been voicing synths since 1980 [for many years actually professionally] & in all that time I only ever used my *ears*.

Comment: @Tetsujin You have never been curious about what are the [shapes behind the sounds](https://youtu.be/qnL40CbuodU?t=21) :P ?

Answer (score 1):

BOSS SY-300 has an audio interface. You can connect it to the computer via USB cable and use any kind of audio recording or visualisation software you like.